# What are the Regular Expression of these sentences

Tags: regex

I am having Problem with Following Reges 
(1)Find all words that begin with letter ‘a’ and end with letter ‘d’. Display the longest of such words.
My Regex for it is this

```
^a[a-zA-Z]+d$
```

but i dont know how to find longest from them...?

(2) count number of even and odd numbers seperately also Display the longest of odd and even numbers.
I have Make R.E For odd is

```
[13579]
```

and for Even is

```
[02468]
```

Comment: then what is Right one @AvinashRaj...

Comment: but you could define it like https://regex101.com/r/fM9gS2/7

Comment: @AvinashRaj Why not? Odd numbers end in an odd digit, while even numbers end in an even digit, no matter what the preceding digits are.

Comment: yep, thats the above regex shows..

Comment: @AvinashRaj Well, OP's regexp matches a single odd or even digit, while he wants to capture the whole number (the longer the better :-)

Comment: @AvinashRaj  i want Seperate R.E to count odd numbers and even i think u'r R.E is counting both of them together...

Comment: for even digits only `\b[02468]+\b` or odd digits `\b[13579]+\b`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Can you suggest R.E for even digits only without \b and ^,$ it will be really helpfull bro....

Comment: you mean this `^[02468]+$` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is not powerful enough to pick the longest string, so you would have to make a program that scans the text with your regular expression, and picks the longest match.

Your first regex is almost good - replace `+` with `*`, otherwise the word `ad` (which starts in `a` and ends in `d` would not be picked. Also replace the `^` and `$` anchors with `\b` on both ends (`\b` means "word boundary"), because you want to scan the text repeatedly for matches.

The second regex should be like this:

```
\b[0-9]*[13579]\b // << Odd numbers
\b[0-9]*[02468]\b // << Even numbers
```

Again, scan the text with these regular expressions, store the longest match as you go, and print it once you reach the end of the text being searched.

Comment: You Mean to say like this \ba[a-zA-Z]*d\b
 @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @UsamaLucky yep, could you provide any failures?(talking about the odd or even numbers)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i want Seperate R.E to count odd numbers and even i think u'r R.E is counting both of them together... –  Usama Lucky 49 secs ago   edit

Comment: @UsamaLucky for longest string, you need to define the range manually https://regex101.com/r/fM9gS2/8

Comment: @UsamaLucky `\b[0-9]*[13579]\b` will match only odd numbers (e.g `22221` or `24685`). Similarly, `\b[0-9]*[02468]\b` matches only even numbers.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i think he wants the number which has only odd digits like [`3759`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059302/what-are-the-regular-expression-of-these-sentences?noredirect=1#comment44500326_28059302). Oh you're an **allrounder**..

Comment: @AvinashRaj In this case I think he misunderstood the assignment, because it clearly says "longest of odd and even numbers", not "longest numbers composed of odd/even digits".

Comment: Grrr, who knows except op.